# Duplicate keys detected: '1'. This may cause an update error. In Vue Element

Tags: vue.js

I am following Vue Element [docs](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#delete-or-add-form-items-dynamically)
Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/684zde2a/

```
<div id="app">

  <el-card class="box-card" v-for="(obj, index) in objEconomForm.objs" :key="obj.key">
      <div>foo</div>
  </el-card>

  <el-card class="box-card"  v-for="(declarer, index) in DeclarerForm.declarers" :key="declarer.key">
     <div>bar</div>
  </el-card>

</div>
```

App:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

    data: {
        DeclarerForm: {
            declarers: [
                {
                    key: 1,
                    xxx: ''
                }
            ]
        },

        objEconomForm: {
            objs: [
                {
                    key: 1,
                    yyy: ''

                }
            ]
        }

    }

})
```

On it I am getting error:
`Duplicate keys detected: '1'. This may cause an update error.`
But keys declared in different objects.

Whats wrong and how it should be fixed in right way?

Comment: for your objects try using: `:key="'obj'+obj.key"` and for declare `:key="'declare'+declarer.key"` this way, your keys shouldn't overlap. And it's clear that your keys are overlapping since there is `key: 1` in both arrays. Think of a `key` like an html `id`

Comment: Rule of thumb: siblings elements should never have the same key.